# Reloading index method

Tags: php, codeigniter

Within my `Backend_controller` which extends my `MY_Controller` I have a function that checks to see if a session exists for the user called `is_logged_in()` and if not then the user is redirected to the login page. When I try and load my login controller it keeps reloading constantly. Any ideas on why this could be?

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !== TRUE)
    {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
        redirect('login','refresh);
    }
}
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's reloading because you are running this code on the login page.  So, on the login page, you are clearly not logged in, so it redirects itself to... the login page!

**Maybe try this**

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !== TRUE)
    {
        if($this->uri->segment(1) !== 'login') redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: What do u suggest I do to alleviate this from continuing to happen.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used CodeIgniter...
You can try and use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and check for `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/login') redirect('login');`.  Or whatever the request uri is on that page.  I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but like I said, it's been awhile!

Comment: That's a great suggestion

Comment: I tried attaching `|| $this->uri->segment(1) !== 'login'` to the end of the if statment check to see if the session is active and it still does the same thing.

Comment: I added code, because simply adding to the or statement doesn't make sense logically.  If you really want it in the if, you need to make it and `&&`.

For example: `(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in !== TRUE) && $this->uri->segment(1) !== 'login'`